# how can i Grab Source code & save it in text file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help to grab the source code of the page & can save it in a text file.

**What actually i want!!**
Instead of doing the lot of work like, right click on the page then click on view source code then to copy & paste it in a text file...

I want to make a short, i want to put a link on the page, in which i need to grab a source code, so when i just click on that link let say "Download Code" it grabs the current page source code & save it in a .txt format.

Kindly help me how can i do this?? it would be great if i can achieve this by using a java script, i don't want to use server side programming language.

I tried data URI but dont get the exact what i need

Comment: @Bulk i tried to use *data uri* but this not the exactly which i can achieve

Comment: @Bulk i mean, i hope it not sounds the stupid one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find some thing on the below link:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewSourceButton/#